# Is there a challenge with which one could reasonably show to have found a feasible polynomial algorithm for an NP problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, p-vs-np

Say there is someone claiming to have solved P vs NP, by finding a (computationally feasible, i.e. no huge constants) polynomial solution to a problem in NP:

Apart from a formal proof, is there any kind of challenge comparable to the [RSA Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers), which could be used to "prove" (or at least give strong evidence) that you have indeed found a polynomial solution to a NP problem?

[For comparison: If I claim to have found a solution to FACTORING and present factors for RSA-2048, that might not actually prove my approach, but would make my attempt a lot more credible]

Comment: "No huge constant" is irrelevant. What matters is the asymptotic behavior.

Comment: If you truly have broken the conjecture, spend the next year learning relevant proof techniques and win the gold watch.

Comment: "give strong evidence" is not enough and probably unrealistic. Non-polynomial behavior is understood "in the worst-case" and we don't know intrinsically worst-case problems. An informal but correct proof could do. By the way, we already have very strong evidence that the conjecture holds.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't think you are addressing the relevant point, which I understood as "suppose one has a practical algorithm for an NP-complete problem, can he prove that without revealing the algorithm?"

Comment: If you can find, in a bunch of previously unbroken hash functions, with independent mechanisms, a preimage to some meaningful hash string, then I believe most people will find that extremely strong evidence you have proven the non-existence of one-way functions, and perhaps even P=NP.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider the following instance of an NP-hard problem: [Eternity II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternity_II_puzzle). This particular instance has been unsolved for more than 15 years, despite dozens of papers about it. Solving this problem would get significant attention, and if it comes with a claim of having a polynomial time algorithm for it, people would definitely be compelled to check it.

Beating the benchmarks in any NP-hard problem, say, on datasets for TSP, or Set Cover, would also be significant enough to draw attention to the new algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

[https://cgi.luddy.indiana.edu/~sabry/cnf.html](https://cgi.luddy.indiana.edu/%7Esabry/cnf.html)

if you have a computationally-feasible program to solve SAT problems (NP-complete), but you don't know how to encode other problems into SAT, this website will encode factoring for you